# Excel Column formatting or VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, I want the numbers to be formatted in the column.

If we enter any other number then I want the number to have dash (-) after the fourth letter. For eg. if we enter 12345678 then I want it to convert to 1234-5678.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the escape character `\`

e.g. number format `0000\-0000`

Enter the string above into a 'Custom' number format

from : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To do it with VBA:

```
Sub fmt()

    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0000\-0000"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

JustinJDavies solution is correct except the escape character is not needed since "-" is not a custom format specifier. It does no harm, neither. So

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0000-0000"
```

(It's working on my 2010. Sorry, not enough reputation to comment)